# Autocomplete displaying [object object] for list items instead of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My jQuery autocomplete looks like this...

[image]

If I do a `console.log` statement I can see that each of the list items actually has the key/value pair that I'm looking for however for whatever reason it won't display properly.I use an Ajax call to populate the list here's what the code looks like

**Controller**

```
    public JsonResult GetDistributorInfo(string term)
    {
        var banks = from c in db.BankListMaster.Where(n => n.BankName.Contains(term))
                    select new
                        {
                            Key = c.ID,
                            Value = c.BankName
                        };

        return Json(banks, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**jQuery/Ajax**

```
    var tempResults = [];
    $(function () {
        $('#DisplayDistributor').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetDistributorInfo", "Agent")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: request,
                    success: function (data) {
                        tempResults = data;
                        response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                            return {
                                label: value,
                                value: key
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                console.log(ui);
                $('#DistributorId').val(tempResults[ui.item.key]);
                $('#DisplayDistributor').text(tempResults[ui.item.value]);

                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data returned is an array of objects. The `value` parameter of your `$.map()` call contains the object, and the `key` parameter is the index of the item in the array (See the first "overload" [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)). So you are setting the object itself as the `label` property, which is why it's being displayed as `[object Object]`.

Try this:

```
response($.map(data, function (item, idx) {
    return {
        label: item.Value,
        value: item.Key
    };
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the item wrongly in the response and select method:

1) Your response should look like:

```
response($.map(data, function (item) {
    return {
        label: item.label,
        value: item.value
    };
}))
```

2) Your select should look like:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    $('#DistributorId').val(tempResults[ui.item.value]); // You are using item.key here
    $('#DisplayDistributor').text(tempResults[ui.item.label]);

    return false;
}
```